# How do I generate a table similar to this and fit to page

Tags: tables

[image]

I was wondering how I would generate a table similar to one shown and fit it to the page.

Comment: Have a look at `tabluarx` package (https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx).

Comment: Of course, all the answers are fine. The first thing that came into my mind was `tabularx`, so here I agree The double lines on top and bottom can easily be made either with `\hline\hline` or `\hhline{===}` (both work here, since the table does not have vertical lines).

Answer (score 4):

For a more practical MWE, I add the two longest cells to test. I chose the first column to be `p{6em}`, that's, large enough for two words like `power control` and use `tabularx` and `ragged2e` as also suggested by others.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,times}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}    

\begin{table}\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{6em}LL@{}}
\toprule
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Conventional Power Plant} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Wind Power Plant}                                                                                                                                                 \\ \midrule
Topology                                               & One or a few large generating units, each unit could be rated at 40 to 1000 MW+ & Typically hundreds of small generators deployed over a large area, each unit could be rated at 1 to 5 MW Wind turbines                   \\
. . .                                                  & . . .                & . . .                                                                                                                                                                                \\
Reactive power control & Units are equipped with an automatic voltage regulator, typically set for voltage control & Reactive power is managed at the plant level, through coordinated control of wind turbine control and/or plant-level reactive compensation\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `p{6em}` is a good idea for the first column. However, why do you remove the small spacing before the first and after the last column using `@{}`?

Comment: @Matthias - The table seems to have long-text cells as you see in the picture of the OP, so it sounds a good idea to gain some more space by using `@`s before the first and after the last columns.

Answer (score 2):

Using the packages `tabularx`, `booktabs` and, as an option, `ragged2e` you can easily achieve the desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lLL}
\toprule
& 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Conventional Power Plant} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Wind Power Plant} \\
\midrule
Topology &
Once or a few large generating units, each unit could be rated \dots &
Typically hundreds of small generators deployed over a large area, each unit \dots \\
Prime mover &
\dots &
\dots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the MWE]

Comment: I'd be tempted to replace the column type for the first column, `l`, with `p{\mylength}`, where `\mylength` is set in the preamble via `\settowidth\mylength{Reactive power}`.

Answer (score 1):

Load `tabularx` and `booktabs` and use

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l*{2}{>{\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
\toprule\midrule
.................................................... \\
\midrule
....................................................
....................................................
.................................................... \\
\midrule\bottomrule
```

You can add some padding between rules with

```
\\
\addlinespace
```

Comment: you should explain what is benefit of use `>{\arraybackslash}X`. it is not so obvious :-)

Answer (score 0):

Like all the preceding answers do, I would highly recommend you look into using the `tabularx` environment and its main column type, called `X`, which allows automatic line-wrapping and expands in width as needed to fill up the available (horizontal) space. And, like the other answers do, I would load the `booktabs` package to generate well-spaced horizontal rules.

Looking at the template provided, I think there's one thing that's missing: automatic hanging indentation of lines beyond the first line. This idea is implemented below. Separately, I also wouldn't center the two headers; left-alignment works just as well (and, arguably, even better).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page size parameters

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e,
            newtxtext,newtxmath}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash
     \hangafter1\hangindent1em}X}
\newcolumntype{q}[1]{>{\raggedright  
     \hangafter1\hangindent1em}p{#1}}

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{Reactive power} % width of first column

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} q{\mylen} YY @{}}
\toprule
& Conventional Power Plant
& Wind Power Plant \\
\midrule
Topology 
& One of a few large generating units. Each unit could be rated at 40 to 1000$+$~MW.
& Typically hundreds of small generators deployed over a large area. Each unit could be rated at 1 to 5~MW. \\
Prime Mover & 
\dots & 
\dots \\
Dispatch
& \dots
& \dots \\
Real power control 
& Units have speed governors and are typically capable of \dots 
& Real power follows the wind speed generation \\
Reactive power control
& Units are equipped with an automatic voltage regulator, typically set for voltage control
& Reactive power is managed at the plant level, through \dots\\
Location & 
\dots & 
\dots \\
Generator 
& Synchronous generators 
&  Type 1---Fixed speed, induction generator; \\
&& Type 2---Variable slip, induction generators with variable rotor resistance; \\
&& \dots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```